# Why does my JList dissapear when updated?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

To preface, I realize this is probably an Event Dispatch Thread issue. I am just unsure where exactly the issue lies.

I have a JList that uses an AbstractListModel to query an object and display the results as a list:

```
public class View {

    public View(final Person person) {
        JList list = new JList(new AbstractListModel() {

            @Override
            public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                return person.getSibling(index);
            }

            @Override
            public int getSize() {
                return person.getNumSiblings();
            }

        });
 }
```

Initially, the JList looks fine - it displays the one sibling that all "Person"s are automatically constructed with. However, when I use something like person.addSibling(...) in another area of my code then the JList turns blank.

Is this an EDT issue? (It appears that after updating a Person the AbstractListModel's methods are no longer called.)

If so, where should I add the SwingWorker code - inside of the AbstractListModel or inside of the person.addSibling(...)?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I am appending a simple, runnable version:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Person person = new Person();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    frame.setContentPane(panel);

                    JList list = new JList(new AbstractListModel() {

                        @Override
                        public Object getElementAt(int index) {
                            return person.getSibling(index);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int getSize() {
                            return person.getNumSiblings();
                        }

                    });
                    panel.add(list);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    person.addSibling("Bob");
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    private static class Person {

        List<String> siblings = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Person() {
            siblings.add("Janice");
        }

        public void addSibling(String sibling) {
            siblings.add(sibling);
        }

        public Object getSibling(int index) {
            return siblings.get(index);
        }

        public int getNumSiblings() {
            return siblings.size();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where's your code that causes the problem? You say this occurs when you call person.addSibling(...), perhaps you should show this code. You ask if this is an EDT/threading issue, but it's hard to say based on the small snippet of code provided. You need to first do some debugging to isolate the problem I think before you can ask for our help, I believe. Our abilities to guess at code not seen is surprisingly poor.

Comment: I've added one of them SSCCSSCEEES things.

I believe the problem is that I am calling person.addSibling("Bob") inside of the EDT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the EDT or threading. You're not calling any of the model's notification methods, `fireXXXX(...)` when the data nucleus of the model changes, and this is messing it up. I suggest you fix this. the [AbstractListModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html) will show the methods that are available for when data is added or removed from the list.

**Edit 1**
Also your model should be in a non-anonymous class that extends `AbstractListModel<String>` and that has an `addSibling(String sib)`  method. You should add the sibling to the model not the Person object.

**Edit 2** e.g.,

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final Person person = new Person();
      final SibListModel listModel = new SibListModel(person);

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
               JFrame frame = new JFrame();
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               JPanel panel = new JPanel();
               frame.setContentPane(panel);

               JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
               panel.add(new JScrollPane(list));
               frame.pack();
               frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               frame.setVisible(true);

               // person.addSibling("Bob");
               listModel.addSibling("Bob");
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });

   }

   private static class SibListModel extends AbstractListModel<String> {
      private Person person;

      public SibListModel(Person person) {
         this.person = person;
      }

      @Override
      public String getElementAt(int index) {
         return person.getSibling(index);
      }

      @Override
      public int getSize() {
         return person.getNumSiblings();
      }

      public void addSibling(String sib) {
         person.addSibling(sib);
         fireIntervalAdded(this, person.getNumSiblings() - 1, person.getNumSiblings());
      }
   }

   private static class Person {

      List<String> siblings = new ArrayList<String>();

      public Person() {
         siblings.add("Janice");
      }

      public void addSibling(String sibling) {
         siblings.add(sibling);
      }

      public String getSibling(int index) {
         return siblings.get(index);
      }

      public int getNumSiblings() {
         return siblings.size();
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but when I move the person.addSibling(...) code outside of the EDT it runs perfectly fine. Is this just coincidence that the list updates at that moment?

Comment: @sdasdadas: the method *should* be called on the EDT only since it is part of the ListModel. How are you calling it outside of the EDT? It's not in a while loop or associated with a `Thread.sleep(...)` that will put the app to sleep is it?

Comment: No, it's not time intensive (or sleeping any threads) since it's just using List.add(...). But, perhaps I am confused in the following:

My JList is a representation of my ListModel, which defers calls to the Person class. Therefore, addSibling isn't really related to the EDT or the GUI - it's related only to the Person class. Everything else is just a representation of the data inside a Person.

Is this wrong?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me because the data belongs inside the data class, not the Swing ListModel. If I happened to have two views, one a JList and the other a JTable, to represent the siblings of a Person it wouldn't be very practical to have them stored in an AbstractListModel...

Comment: @sdasdadas: see edit 2, my SSCCE. You'll see that it works. ListModel is a data class of sorts, and all changes to the list need to go through the model.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I'm going to play with it in my original code a bit but thanks for all the help.